# Не могу подключиться к докеру с хоста

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

Всем привет, недавно стал изучать докер. Есть 2 сервиса на spring boot один настроен на 8081 порт, другой по умолчанию на 8080. Если запускаю их на хосте, то все норм коннектиться по localhost:8080/... Я решил перенести все это в докер. Использую docker-compose и Dockerfile для каждого сервиса. Вот код:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: testtest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
    healthcheck:
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=testtest --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
  
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  
  receipt:
    container_name: receipt
    build: ./receipt
    ports: 
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      KAFKA_SERVER: kafka:9092
    depends_on: 
      - kafka

  hotel:
    container_name: hotel
    build: ./hotel
    hostname: hotel
    ports: 
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: mysql:3306
      KAFKA_SERVER: kafka:9092
    depends_on: 
      - kafka 
      - mysql
```

вот докерфалйл на сервис hotel(надо именно до него достучаться):

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi
VOLUME /tmp
ADD ./hotel.jar app.jar
CMD sleep 60 && java -jar app.jar
```

Сами сервисы поднимаются нормально, ошибок нет в логах. Вот так выглядит инфа о них:

[image: скрин с выводом команды docker ps]

На то что в конце нет контейнеров не смотрите, просто я их вручную вырубил. Как я вижу, порты прокинуты, но при попытке зайти на них через постман или просто браузер он их никак не обнаруживает. Проблема именно на моей машине, т.к. этот проект отлично прошел тест на другом компе. Если что, у меня win 8 64x. В чем может быть дело? Брандмауэр отключал, не помогло. Может быть кто сталкивался?

Comment: логи контейнера проверяли? и на каком адресе стартует приложение, что стоит в конфигурации `server.address`?

Comment: Ничего не стоит, по умолчанию же на 8080 встает, нет? Логи не проверял, ибо не знал что они есть)) Сейчас гляну, спасибо!)

Comment: В логах пишет что tomcat на 8080(http). Сами логи хорошие, без ошибок. Поробовал поставить server.address=127.0.0.1 Не помогло

Comment: у вас получилось решить вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. контейнер изолирован от хост системы (запускается внутри виртуальной сети `172.x.x.x`), то `127.0.0.1`/`localhost` внутри контейнера, это адреса, которые будут доступны только внутри контейнера, если вы хотите получить доступ снаружи, то нужно использовать `server.address`=`0.0.0.0` адрес, это приведет к тому, что приложение будет слушать указанный порт на всех адресах.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш совет. К сожалению, в моем случае проблема так и осталась. Сделал в спринг буте соответствующую настройку server.address=0.0.0.0, но до сих пор, если пытаюсь подключиться через постман или браузер выдает: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080(постман) и такое же браузер.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подключиться к контейнеру по адресу localhost:8080

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Уже пробовал, не помогает.